# SpringBoot: Can't Autowire Class from Other Jar Library

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am developing a SpringBoot application (e.g. MyApp) with dependency to two data projects with different implementation:

> data-jdbc.jar

- built using the `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` which exposes JDBCDataService class that will be used by my application

Sample Code:

```
@Service 
public class JDBCDataServiceImpl implements JDBCDataService {

@Autowired
private JDBCDataRepository jdbcDataRepository;    
... 
}
```

- with package `my.data.jdbc`
- there is no SpringBoot main class. Spring configuration only created for the unit test classes
- the repository classes are using `JDBCTemplate`

Sample Repository:

```
@Repository
public class JDBCDataRepositoryImpl implements JDBCDataRepository {

@Autowired
protected JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
...
}
```

> data-jpa.jar

- built using the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` which also exposes JPADataService class that will also be used by my application

Sample Code:

```
@Service 
public class JPADataServiceImpl implements JPADataService {

@Autowired
private JPADataRepository jpaDataRepository;    
... 
}
```

- with package `my.data.jpa`
- there is no SpringBoot main class. Spring configuration only created for the unit test classes
- repository classes extends the `CrudRepository` interface

Sample Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface JPADataRepository extends CrudRepository<MyObject, Integer{
...
}
```

In my SpringBoot project, I have the following SpringBoot main application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
}
```

In my business service `MainService` class, I have the following injection

```
@Service
public class MainServiceImpl implements MainService {

@Autowired
private JDBCDataService jdbcDataService;

@Autowired
private JPADataService jpaDataService;
```

However, I have encountered the problem `"Could not Autowire. No beans of 'JPADataService' type found"` which only exists for the class `JPADataService` but working fine for `JDBCService` class.

I have tried the solution found in the following questions, but none of these work in my case:

[Can't I @Autowire a Bean which is present in a dependent Library Jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30796306/cant-i-autowire-a-bean-which-is-present-in-a-dependent-library-jar)

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.example.main", "package.of.user.class"})
```

[How can I @Autowire a spring bean that was created from an external jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29571304/how-can-i-autowire-a-spring-bean-that-was-created-from-an-external-jar)

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.package.where.my.class.is")
class Config {
...
}
```

I have now found the solution on my problem. I have to move up my main MyApp.java one package level higher in order to scan my data libraries.

Instead of putting my `MyApp.java` under `my.app` package, I have to move it under `my` in order to successfully scan my libraries with `my.data.jpa` and `my.data.jdbc` packages.

Comment: `@ComponentScan` will only work if the `JPADataService` class is annotated with `@Component`. You need to add an `@Bean` annotated method in your `@Configuration` class. http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.m3/reference/html/creating-bean-definitions.html

Comment: @Christopher Schneider ,both service classes in both jar files are actually annotated with `@Service`. AFAIK, `@ComponentScan` should also be able to read those classes.

Comment: @Service should take care of it. You say you have no main class, so where is the entry point to the application?

Comment: The entry point is in my new SpringBoot app (MyApp) that I am developing, so I have those data as my dependency in my maven project.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have now found the solution on my problem. I have to move up my main MyApp.java one package level higher in order to scan my data libraries.

Instead of putting my `MyApp.java` under `my.app` package, I have to move it under `my` in order to successfully scan my libraries with `my.data.jpa` and `my.data.jdbc` packages.

Comment: Why did this happen? It's a bug or a spring-boot feature?

Comment: It's not a bug, @ComponentScan by default picks up from package where main class is defined and it's sub-directories

Comment: You are a life savior @Jown. I spent almost a day to figure out the problem in my application. I added ComponentScan to my SpringBoot main application calls, it solved the actual problem, but that caused some other problem internal to my app. I have moved the SpringBoot main class, and it solved my problem. Literally you have saved my weekend.. kudos!

Answer (score 12):

Adding `@ComponentScan` won't work if the class you're attempting to Autowire isn't annotated with `@Component`. In order to get this to work, you'll have to annotate a method in your `@Configuration` class. Something like this should allow you to autowire the class:

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigClass{

    @Bean
    public JPADataService jpaDataService(){
        return new JPADataService();
    }
}
```

Comment: I should add I'm not familiar with JPADataService. It may require some sort of configuration that I didn't account for.

Comment: If this is the case, it should also not work in `JDBCService` object as I have not declared this class in any Java configuration file in my application which uses them. AFAIK, using `@SpringBootApplication` should do the magic for you :-)

Comment: anybody know why '@ComponentScan' wont work? I am facing the same issue, my repository is even annotated with '@Repository' and added a ComponentScan with base package value, which is one level up where spring could see all the beans even from jar libraries. The application only worked when I moved up one level the SpringBootApplication as @Jown said.

Answer (score 2):

You need to config `spring.factories` at external jar:

```
external-jar-project
   |--java
   |--resources
        |-- META-INF
              |-- spring.factories
```

the contect of spring.factoires, like this:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=xxx
```

Answer (score -6):

This problem has also bothered me for a long time. What I found is that springboot cannot scan the related classes under the jar package path you introduced.

You may need to use annotations like @EnableJpaRepositories ("cn.XXX") @EntityScan ("cn.XXX") to Scan your classes)